# Mouse control using Twilio's screen share session

Tags: keyboard, twilio, mouse, remote-access, twilio-php

Here is my situation. **I have used Twilio on my portal** for "creating s meeting + chat + screen share" and **want to add hand-over mouse control** as in join.me, zoom, teamviewer. *Is there any api, sdk or any way to achieve that while using Twilio for screen-sharing*, as I have already paid for Twilio I can not opt for other integrations for meetings. Or is it possible to leverage the facility of any other application with Twilio.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing is to make use of the Twilio Programmable Video Data Tracks API.

[Announcing Programmable Video DataTracks API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/programmable-video-launches-datatrack.html)